# Tab in edit mode in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tabs, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am trying to Implement  Tab control in MVC 4 , I want similar like Nopcommerce
if you login in admin -->sale -->Order -->View

I am not able to understand how to do this ?
Url is not changes in every case only change the tab value .

I am attaching screen short for reference .

Please guide me how to achieve this

Thanks in Advance   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same tabs using the Telerik Extensions (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/tabstrip).

Comment: Hi Mariann , thanks for your reply but i did not use any third party .but i did that